# Better PK for future safe data intensive Databases

Tags: mysql, database

We are really having a technical trouble of designing the primary keys for our new data intensive project.

Please explain us which PK design is better for our data intensive database.

1. The database is data intensive and persistence.
2. Atleast 3000 users access it per second.

Please tell us technically which type of PK is better for our database and the tables are less likely to change in the future.

1.INT/BIGINT auto increment column as PK

2.Composite keys.

3.Unique varchar PK.

Comment: It makes almost no difference at all.

Comment: so using multiple columns for composite key doesn't degrade performance?

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL? How are you evaluating better? Most future proof? Least chance of collision? Least memory? Is this 3000 reads per second, or 3000 writes per second, or a mixture (if so what ratio)? What are the types for your composite key? Are they guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: its mysql, lease chance of collision we are expecting and its mostly writes:reads per second ration would be 7:3 and types of composite keys are 3-4 columns of bigint, as per our design report

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for option 1, using a BIGINT autoincrement column as the PK. The reason is simple, each write will write to the end of the current page, meaning inserting new rows is very fast. If you use a composite key, then you need an order, and unless you are inserting in the order of the composite key, then you need to split pages to insert, e.g. Imagine this table:

```
 A | B | C
---+---+---
 1 | 1 | 4
 1 | 4 | 5
 5 | 1 | 2
```

Where the primary key is a composite key on (A, B, C), suppose I want to insert (2, 2, 2), it would need to be inserted as follows:

```
 A | B | C
---+---+---
 1 | 1 | 4
 1 | 4 | 5
 2 | 2 | 2 <----
 5 | 1 | 2
```

So that the clustered key maintains its order. If the page you are already inserting too is already full, then MySQL will need to split the page, moving some of the data to a new page to make room for the new data. These page splits are quite costly, so unless you know you are inserting sequential data then using an autoincrement column as the clustering key means that unless you mess around with the increments you should never have to split a page.

You could still add a unique index to the columns that would be the primary key to maintain integrity, you would still have the same problem with splits on the index, but since the index would be narrower than a clustered index the splits would be less frequent as more data will fit on a page.

More or less the same argument applies against a unique varchar column, unless you have some kind of process that ensures the varchar is sequential, but generating a sequential varchar is more costly than an autoincrement column, and I can see no immediate advantage.

Comment: Thanks that would help us alot in further process

Comment: what if the auto increment reaches its limit? because the tables fills up everyday with millions of rows.

Comment: [The limit of an unsigned BIGINT is](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-type-overview.html) 18,446,744,073,709,551,615 - Even if you are inserting 1,000,000 records per second, it will take you 584,542 years to reach the limit. I am pretty certain your database will become unusably large before you reach the limit of BIGINT.

Answer (score 1):

This is not easy to answer.

To start with, using composite keys as primary keys is the straight-forward way. IDs come in handy when the database structure changes.

Say you have products in different sizes sold in different countries. Primary keys are bold.

- product (**product_no**, name, supplier_no, ...)
- product_size (**product_no, size**, ean, measures, ...)
- product_country (**product_no, country_isocode**, translated_name, ...)
- product_size_country (**product_no, size, country_isocode**, vat, ...)

It is very easy to wite data, because you are dealing with natural keys, which is what users work with. The dbms garantees data consistency.

Now the same with technical IDs:

- product (**product_id**, product_no, name, supplier_no, ...)
- product_size (**product_size_id**, size, product_id, ean, measures, ...)
- product_country (**product_country_id**, product_id, country_id, translated_name, ...)
- product_size_country (**product_size_country_id**, product_size_id, country_id, vat, ...)

To get the IDs is an additional step needed now, when inserting data. And still you must ensure that product_no is unique. So the unique constraint on product_id doesn't replace that constraint on product_no, but adds to it. Same for product_size, product_country and product_size_country. Moreover product_size_country may now link to product_country and product_size_country of different products. The dbms cannot guarantee data consistency any longer.

However, natural keys have their weakness when changes to the database structure must be made. Let's say that a new company is introduced in the database and product numbers are only unique per company. With the ID based database you would simply add a company ID to the products table and be done. In the natural key based database you would have to add the company to all primary keys. Much more work. (However, how often must such changes be made to a database. In many databases never.)

What more is there to consider? When the database gets big, you might want to partitionate tables. With natural keys, you could partition your tables by said company, assuming that you will usually want to select data from one company or the other. With IDs, what would you partition the tables by to enhance access?

Well, both concepts certainly have pros and cons. As to your third option to create a unique varchar, I see no benefit in this over using integer IDs.

Comment: we are thinking about the speed of writing and reading, and the tables may change in future to add or remove some column, in the view of fast writing and reading which would be the best way?

Comment: There shouldn't be much difference in the speed with the two techniques. Theoretically to access via a single number instead of a composite key should be slightly faster, but I don't think that the difference will measurable. So reading and updating (as one doesn't update keys usually) should be equally fast. As to inserting data: This should be faster with composite keys. The reason is that a technical ID is something additional. As mentioned you will have the same unique constraints, which means the same unique index to write *plus* the unique index for the ID. ...

Comment: Partioning tables, intelligently done, can speed up data access further. And I consider this to be easier with natural keys, as mentioned above. I must admit, however, that I don't know if partioning has positive or negative impact on inserts.